# How to have blank lines in a .text.haml document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm creating an email notification in a `.text.haml` document. How does one denote a blank line?

```
= @variable.name + " , you have a new update."
=
=
= "There has been new activity."
```

In the above example I would like the two lines that have just the HAML `=` on them to be blank lines but just having the `=` signs causes an error.  What should I be doing?

Answer (score 23):

Blank lines in a .haml.text document can be created by placing a \ on a line by itself. An example in the form of an email:

```
Dear #{@user.name},
\
Use a backslash for blank lines in haml text templates.
\
Thanks!
```

However, HAML is designed for creating HTML documents, not plaintext ones. You really would be better off using `erb` or something else for this.

Comment: How can I do this within a block? e.g. `User.each do |user|` ? It doesn't seem to work with leading white spaces

Comment: HAML really isn't designed for creating plaintext documents. My best advice here would be not to use HAML.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it would look like (check the whitespace in the two lines):

```
== #{@variable.name} , you have a new update.
:preserve


There has been new activity.
```

But HAML isn't really made for this kind of usage.

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* you can do this:

```
= "... a new update.\n\n"
```

The `\n` means a new line. I don't have HAML before me to test it out.

If it's making HTML, you can also just add:

```
%br
%br
```

To make HTML new lines.